# Get ga:source from ga:eventLabel in google analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I know eventLabel beforehand and I want to query the API such that I get the corresponding source.

I've tried https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/request-composer/ but there was no option for explicitly providing eventLabel value.

Answer (score 1):

Google made some changes to the Request Composer and now you need to select the request type first. If you select Pivot Request (the second tab) you'll have the option to pick ga:eventLabel, ga:source as dimensions.

Comment: I think you might be confusing [Query Explorer - QE](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) and [Request Composer - RC](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/request-composer/). QE is a simple parameter based tool to query the V3 reporting API. RC is a more complicated tool designed to make the more advanced requests only possible in V4 Analytics Reporting API.